# Weird Output with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I wanted to see if anyone can explain a bit how Handlebars chooses to indent, break lines, etc. I am at a loss.

Given the following code:

```
"use strict";

const hbars = require("handlebars");

const item_renderer = `{ 
    name: "{{name}}"{{#if family}},
    family: [
        {{#each family}}
        {{> item_renderer}}{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    ]
    {{/if}}
}`;

hbars.registerPartial("item_renderer", item_renderer);
let templ = hbars.compile(`{{> item_renderer}}`);


const data = {
    name: "John",
    family: [
        {
            name: "Joan",
            family: [
                { name: "Jim", }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

console.log(templ(data));
```

I would like (and expect) this code to output the following text:

```
{ 
    name: "John",
    family: [
        { 
            name: "Joan",
            family: [
                { 
                    name: "Jim"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

however the actual output is:

```
{ 
    name: "John",
    family: [
        { 
    name: "Joan",
    family: [
        { 
    name: "Jim"}
    ]
}
    ]
}
```

I can get closer if I tweak the partial a bit, for instance by moving the conditional "comma" in the "family" loop to a new line:

```
const item_renderer = `{ 
    name: "{{name}}"{{#if family}},
    family: [
        {{#each family}}
        {{> item_renderer}}
{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
        {{/each}}
    ]
    {{/if}}
}`;
```

Now I get this:

```
{ 
    name: "John",
    family: [
        { 
            name: "Joan",
            family: [
                { 
                    name: "Jim"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Not perfect but getting close. The issue now is with the last inner most child, the closing bracket was not placed in the new line so somehow the condition of the "unless" helper is affecting the insertion of the new line character that follows. I can add a line break after the final "IF" block, but this inserts empty lines for the items that have the "family" array.

It seems to me I must be missing something pretty fundamental about how this stuff is support to work, any ideas?

Thanks!

-Carlos

Comment: What difference does it make? Indentation isn't significant in JavaScript syntax, so as long as the template expands to correct code it'll work.

Comment: @Pointy if they're using handlebars, it's likely they're using `<pre>` format to display output intended to be readable.

Comment: I picked a very simple example just to illustrate the behaviour, if we were to generating python code for instance, it would be necessary to get the indentation right.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I suppose that's possible, but nothing in the question suggests it has anything to do with HTML — an interesting fact in itself, as my tacit assumption would be that Handlebars is primarily intended and used for generating HTML markup.